# Rank of a combinatorial matrix

Tags: combinatorics, homology-cohomology

The following -- seemingly purely combinatorial -- problem arose in a cohomology computation:

Let $n$ be an integer and denote by $C^1$ the set of (ordered) $2$-tuples with entries in $0,\dotsc,n$ and by $C^2$ the set of (ordered) $3$-tuples. In the following, we want to consider $C^1$ and $C^2$ as free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.

Consider that map $d\colon C^1\to C^2$ that sends a tuple $(i,j)$ to $f(i,j)\cdot(l,m,n)$ where
$$f(i,j)=\begin{cases}1,&\text{if $i=l$ and $j=m$,}\\-1,&\text{if $i=l$ and $j=n$,}\\1,&\text{if $i=m$ and $j=n$,}\\0,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
We can then describe this map via an $\binom{n+1}{3}\times\binom{n+1}{2}$ matrix $M_n$.

For example: For $n=2$ there are three $2$-tuples $(0,1), (0,2)$ and $(1,2)$ and one $3$-tuple $(0,1,2)$. Therefore $M_2=(1,-1,1)$.

For $n=3$ there are six $2$-tuples $(0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (1,2), (1,3), (2,3)$ and four $3$-tuples $(0,1,2), (0,1,3), (0,2,3), (1,2,3)$. Therefore
$$M_3=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&0&1&0&0\\1&0&-1&0&1&0\\0&1&-1&0&0&1\\0&0&0&1&-1&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

The rank of $M_2$ is obviously $1$, the rank of $M_3$ is $3$ and $M_4$ is a $10\times 10$ matrix of rank $6$.

I claim that the rank of $M_n$ is always $\binom{n}{2}$ but I see no easy/down-to-earth combinatorial proof of this and would be very grateful for any suggestions or references.

Comment: It sounds like when you say "ordered tuples" you mean you want the elements of the tuples to be in increasing order. Usually "ordered tuples" just means that the elements of the tuples come in an order (so that there is a first element, a second element, etc.); with the standard definition the number of ordered $k$-tuples is $n^k$. Also, it's a little strange to talk about considering a finite set as a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module; you mean you want to consider the free $\mathbb{Z}$-module on these finite sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the exterior algebra on the vector space $V$ of dimension $n+1$
over your favourite field. Write $e_0,\ldots,e_n$ for basis elements.
We identify pairs $(i,j)$ with $i<j$ with basis elements $e_i\wedge e_j$
of the second exterior power $\bigwedge^2 V$ and
We identify triples $(i,j,k)$ with $i<j<k$ with basis elements $e_i\wedge e_j\wedge e_k$ of the third exterior power $\bigwedge^3 V$.
Multiplication on the right by $\omega =e_0+e_1+\cdots+e_n$ gives a map
from $\bigwedge^2 V$ to $\bigwedge^3 V$ which is given by your matrix.
We can change bases by an automorphism of $V$ to take $\omega$ to $e_0$.
This conjugates the map $-\wedge\omega$ to $-\wedge e_0$ which is easy
to see is of rank $\binom n2$: it kills $e_0\wedge e_j$ and sends
$e_i\wedge e_j$ to $e_0\wedge e_i\wedge e_j$ for $0<i<j$, and these
are linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you! This was just what I was looking for :)